Nginx proxy original IP issue
I'm looking to add a proxy for my FiveM server, but when I get the IP of the player it returns the proxy's IP address.
I also want to use Cloudflare Tunnels, I'm sure that would also cause the same issue
My sites-available:
upstream backend {
    server FIVEM_SERVER_IP:30120;
}

proxy_cache_path /srv/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=assets:48m max_size=20g inactive=2h;

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name play.my-server.com;

    set_real_ip_from PROXY_IP/32;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}


I tried all I can to fix it, but no luck :(
I tried everything I could find online :)
